# How to implement apple like camera app using AVCaptureSession?

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

In the iOS(9) camera app the controls overlay does not rotate but when 'Record' is selected the video is outputted with the correct orientation. Has anyone got any ideas how apple implemented this.

Comment: They most likely kept track of the rotation using a notification to detect a rotation and then `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation` to get the actual rotation of the device. Then using this, they rotate only the camera to match the orientation of the device. This is all while restricting the app itself to only one orientation (portrait in this case).

Comment: You still get a clunky animation though were as the Camera app doesn't appear to rotate at all. Thanks the reply.

Comment: You could set the animation duration of the transform to 0.

Comment: You could even set the capture orientation of the capture session to match the devices while keeping the preview orientation the same. [Check this out for a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236093/avcapturesession-rotate-orientation-while-video-transmitting)

Comment: I didn't realise we had access to that property?

Comment: Mate you are a legend!! I am now only changing the connections orientation and leaving the view orientation alone. You should add that as the answer so I can accept it. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few different options to achieve the same effect:

You can rotate the camera, but keep the UI the same, when the device itself is rotated so that it matches `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation`.

You could store the device orientation at the time of capture and then rotate the video afterwards.

You could even set the capture connection of the capture session to match the devices orientation while keeping the preview connection the same. [Check this out for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236093/avcapturesession-rotate-orientation-while-video-transmitting)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented exactly what you're looking for using 2 different UIWindow instances, one for the video preview layer and one for the UI to be displayed on top of it. The UIWindow with the UI needs to have a transparent background in order for the preview layer to remain visible.